# Xamarin.iOS VSTS Failed to add the temporary keychain to the keychains search path

Tags: xamarin.ios, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I try to build an Xamarin.iOS application with the corresponding VSTS tasks "Build Xamarin.iOS solution".
The repository contains a certificate file .p12 and a provisioning profile.
Under "Signing & Provisioning" I'm using File Contents with the path to the certificate (and corresponding password) and the provisioning profile.

As build agent I'm using a macincloud VSTS agent.

But I always get the error "Failed to add the temporary keychain to the keychains search path". The following lines are the output before the tasks returns with this error message.

```
[command]/usr/bin/security import certificates.p12 -P ****** -A -t cert -f pkcs12 -k _xamariniostasktmp.keychain
2 identities imported.
[command]/usr/bin/security list-keychain -d user
[command]/usr/bin/security list-keychain -d user
```

Thx a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [blog](http://www.blogaboutxamarin.com/xamarin-dev-ops-with-vsts-setup-ios-ci-builds-with-macincloud/) about setting up Xamarin.iOS CI Builds With MacinCloud.

You may lose the step to setup the .p12 and provisioning profile in MacinCloud portal.

**Update:**

Thanks for @Stephan 's comment which mentioned the delay of the process after you upload them.

> Turned out that it requires few minutes for the p12 certificate and provisioning profile to be available in MacInCloud after uploading them. I did queue a new build directly after uploading them. Now it works.

Comment: @drvj, did my answer help you?

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue. Adding p12 ans provisioning profile in the MacInCloud portal didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: This actually is the correct answer. Turned out that it requires few minutes for the p12 certificate and provisioning profile to be available in MacInCloud after uploading them. I did queue a new build directly after uploading them. Now it works.

Comment: Thanks, @Stephan. You may update an answer for this case.